# How do I split a word on the capital letters?

Tags: javascript

I want to change, for example, "FileNotFound" into "File Not Found".

The obvious

```
"FileNotFound".split(/[A-Z]/g).join(" ")
```

returns "ile ot ound", which makes me sound like I have some kind of speech defect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to split camel case](//stackoverflow.com/q/18379254)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the self-answer, but I thought this was neat.  *More* neat answers welcome.

The most obvious solution, although the one I found the last, is

```
"FileNotFound".replace(/[A-Z]/g, a => " " + a).trim()
```

A more educational solution (imo) is this:

```
"FileNotFound".split(/(?=[A-Z])/g).join(" ")
```

The `?=` means "lookahead", so "match the empty string, so long as it is followed by a capital letter".  This solution is probably slower, but doesn't disturb any pre-existing white-space on the front, and is easier to generalize.

Answer (score 0):

The more *neat* solution:

```js
console.log("FileNotFound".replace(/([A-Z][a-z]+)(?=[A-Z])/g, "$1 "));
```

Comment: What would it do on "File1NotFound"?

Comment: you would do `"File1NotFound".replace(/([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)(?=[A-Z])/g, "$1 ")`